# Having Trouble With SQL JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with a MySQL JOIN and was wondering if someone could help me out. Real quick overview on the tables I'm joining.

`User` Table Columns (just the columns that matter in this case):

```
userId | active | role | username | addressId
```

`Address` Table Columns (just the columns that matter in this case):

```
addressId | firstName | lastName
```

`ManagerRepRelationship` table

`repId | managerId`

Here are the relationships between these tables:

- When a new User is created, they get assigned a key (userId) and their address information gets it's own row in Address with a key (addressId). That addressId key gets stores with the users row in the User table.
- Also, when a user is created they are assigned one of two roles: 'manager' or 'representative'. If they are a representative, they must be assigned a manager (so obviously, some managers need to be created before any reps can be). When a rep is assigned to a manager and created, the rep's `userID` is stored into the `ManagerRepRelationship` in the `repId` column, at the same time the manager's `userId` chosen for this rep is stored in the same row under the `managerId` column.

Here is the trouble I am having. When it comes to editing a representative, I want to echo the name of the manager that is assigned to that rep at the top. On the edit page, I am passing the edited representative's `userId` in the url so it is available with `$_GET["userID']`.

I cannot seem to write the correct JOIN statement to get back the first and last name of the manager, not the rep being edited. Here is what I have so far but I am getting null. I hope I explained this well enough.

```
<?php
  $user_id = $_GET["userId"]; // the rep getting edited userId
  // grab all the reps address info and user info
  $user_result = mysqli_query( $connection,
                "SELECT Users.*, Address.*
                 FROM Users
                  JOIN Address
                  ON Users.addressId=Address.addressId
                 WHERE Users.userId=" . $user_id
              );
  $user_set = mysqli_fetch_array($user_result);

 // Trying to get the first and last name of the manager
 // That is assigned to this rep
   $result = mysqli_query( $connection,
                    "SELECT A.firstName, A.lastName
                     FROM Address A
                      JOIN Users U
                      ON A.addressId=U.addressId
                      JOIN ManagerRepRelationship M
                      ON M.repId=U.userId AND M.managerID=U.userId
                     WHERE U.role='manager' AND M.repId=" . $user_id
                   );
   $managerName = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

Comment: oops sorry. one sec. i need to edit this.

Comment: check for errors on the queries http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and possibly error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: The foreign key relationship between your `User` table and your `Address` table is backwards. If you wish to have a 1:many relationship between users and addresses, your `Address` table should have a `userId` column and the `User` table should *not* have an `addressId` column. Think about this: If your `addressId` column is non-nullable in the `User` table, and foreign keys are enforced, you would need to insert the user's address *before* inserting the user, which definitely feels backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This condition:

```
ON M.repId=U.userId AND M.managerID=U.userId
```

will only be true if a person is their own manager.  I think what your looking for is something like this:

```
"SELECT
   A.firstName, A.lastName
FROM 
   Address A
   JOIN Users U ON A.addressId=U.addressId
   JOIN ManagerRepRelationship M ON M.managerID=U.userId
   WHERE U.role='manager' AND M.repId=" . $user_id
```

It should also be mentioned that your code is susceptible to SQL Injection and is therefore quite insecure.

Comment: I am sanitizing my variables. Just felt it was overkill to put that code in this question. Thanks for the input!

Comment: This is is correct answer and works PERFECTLY! Up-vote and answered question for you sir! Thank you!